# How to get server URL or base URL in Spring Securtiy XML config file?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am using Spring, Spring Security, CAS login and Maven in my web application.
At the time of CAS (central authentication service) login I need service URL in config file.

Can I get server URL or base URL of my application in Spring Security XML config file without hard code on any other place?

Comment: What do you mean by server URL? A server cannot possibly know it's URL...

Comment: Server URL means In case of Localhost - http://localhost:800.. Like that

Comment: or if i improve my question then i need application base URL.

Comment: And if localhost is a server accessible on `https://gourav.saklecha.org` and I forward traffic from port `80` to port `8080` how is the server supposed to know that? And if there is a proxy that sends traffic from `https://boris.the.spider.org` to `https://gourav.saklecha.org`?

Comment: Server means where i deployed my application. in case tomcat provide default starting url - localhost.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  The server is always deployed on itself - i.e. localhost.

Comment: ignore server url. I just need base url of my application.

Comment: for example if i deploy gourav war on tomcat then i can access this war by 
using this url - http://localhost:8080/gourav/

Comment: SO i need this url in config file.

Comment: See my comment above. The URL on which you can access your server is not something the server can know.

Comment: So i need to hard code base url in pom.xml or config flle?

Comment: It's not something you can know either in the general case. This seems to be an XY problem - what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: means i am not accessing any other server from my application. I am just using my application deploy on my server and i only need base url of my application.

Comment: I am just authenticating my application from cas server and there is need of service url(base url)  that is redirect url or callback url after successful authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/reference/cas.html) right, you have to write the URL into the configuration:

```
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/cas-sample/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

If I understand [ServiceProperties#getService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/cas/ServiceProperties.html#getService--) right, it don't support relativ URLs.

> Represents the service the user is authenticating to.
>
> This service is the callback URL belonging to the local Spring Security System for Spring secured application. For example,
>
> ```
> https://www.mycompany.com/application/login/cas
> ```

In general, you don't know the URL until you get a request, see [ServletRequest#getLocalName](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalName()):

> Returns the host name of the Internet Protocol (IP) interface on which the request was received.